# Jqgrid in Asp.net not MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Am new for jqgrid in asp.net.I dont know how to connect the sqlserver 2005 table with jqgrid.I search in google.But i cant able to get material for doing this.can anyone know the website or refernce for do this?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can get started on the [Demo Page](http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx), under the section `Demos for ASP.NET WebForms 3.5+`.

See also the [jqGrid for ASP.NET Documentation](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/aspnet/index.htm).